# Can an optional embedded field be omitted, even when a mandatory dropdown field is included?

Tags: cme, schema

We have a schema that includes an optional multivalue embedded field. The schema for this embedded field has 3 optional single text fields, 2 mandatory single text fields and 1 mandatory dropdown select field.

The problem we encounter is that whenever you create a new component based on this schema, you HAVE to fill in all the mandatory fields in the embedded fields in this component, even though the embedded field itself is optional. The cause of this seems to be the mandatory dropdown field that is prefilled by Tridion.

It seems the only workaround is to make the embedded dropdown select field optional.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Without the drop-down, an optional embedded Schema would let you save even with mandatory fields from the embedded Schema, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. So the problem is purely about the dropdown field blocking the optional embedded schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have flexibility to switch the field types, you might consider changing the dropdown to a radio button since it also only allows one value to be selected, as in a dropdown, but isn't prepopulated by Tridion when you create a new component.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a good solution. Although the only issue I see with this solution is that you can't deselect the radio button.

Comment: You can deselect a radio button by switching to the "Source" tab and deleting the XML node corresponding to your field.

Comment: I'd rather not let the content editor edit the source tab. You never know what they do with that kind of power. We have created a ticket for SDL to look at it. It seems like something they could solve.

Answer (score 2):

There is one other solution proposed by a colleague. And that is to change the field to a keyword selection field (type Tree in schema field specification). This will allow you to select a keyword and empty the field when you need to. 
When left empty it will not add the optional embedded field element to your component XML

Comment: This solution works for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if the embedded field is optional, you shouldn't be required to fill in the dropdown within it, but the way embedded fields are pre-loaded does not allow for that. The problem is that the mandatory fields within the embeddable field have some default values assigned to them, which make the embedded field having a value in one of its embedded fields, forcing Tridion to validate the rest of the embedded fields.

[image: Embedded mandatory field prepopulated from list]

You can remove the embedded field from the "Source" tab as somebody suggests in another answer:

[image]

but I guess that's not optimal for Content Managers.

So I would recommend making the dropdown field optional and only enforce its value via Event System if any of the other two are set (basically you will be doing the mandatory check... but only if the others are set).

Comment: I tried removing it from the source tab. But even then, when you return to your form view of your component it will recreate this node.